# HTML form sends Null to php

Tags: php, html, forms

I am using forms to register users and send the form values to the php. But I on and on get null instead of the real values.

My Html:

```
<div class="third">
    <h2 class="section-title">Register now</h2>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="box-style cont-pad">
                    <form method = "post" action = "register.php" >
                        <h2>Please Sign Up <small>It is free and always will be.</small></h2>
                        <hr class="colorgraph"> 
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group form-actions">
                                    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="First Name" tabindex="1">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Last Name" tabindex="2">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email Address" tabindex="3">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="age" name="Age" id="Age" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Age" tabindex="4"  >
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2"> <span class="radio">
                            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" class="o-hidden" value="1"  tabindex="5" align="middle">Male   
                        </span> </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10"> <span class="radio">
                            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" class="o-hidden" value="0" tabindex="6"  align="middle">Female
                        </span> </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2"> <span class="radio">
                            <input type="radio" name="status" id="female" class="o-hidden" value="1"  tabindex="7" >Enduser
                        </span> </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3"> <span class="radio">
                            <input type="radio" name="status" id="female" class="o-hidden" value="0" tabindex="8" >Company
                        </span> </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2"> <span class="radio">
                            <input type="radio" name="status" id="female" class="o-hidden" value="10" tabindex="9" >Both
                        </span> </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" tabindex="10">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Confirm Password" tabindex="11">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1"> <span class="button-checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="t_and_c" id="t_and_c" class="o-hidden" value="1" tabindex="12" >
                            </span> </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11 col-md-11">
                                <p>By clicking <strong class="label label-primary">Register</strong>, you agree to the <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#t_and_c_m">Terms and Conditions</a> set out by this site, including our Cookie Use.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="colorgraph">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                                <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" tabindex="13">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg" tabindex="14" >Sign In</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
require_once 'include/Functions-reg-log.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
try{
    $response = array("error" => FALSE);
    if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['surname']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['age']) && isset($_POST['sex']) && isset($_POST['status']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['t_and_c'])) 
    {

        // receiving the post params
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $surname = $_POST['surname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $age = $_POST['age'];
        $sex = $_POST['sex'];
        $status = $_POST['status'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        // check if user is already existed with the same email
        if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {
            // user already existed
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed with " . $email;
            echo json_encode($response);
        } 
        else 
        {
            // create a new user
            $user = $db->storeUser($name,$surname, $email, $age, $sex, $status, $password);
            if ($user) {
                // user stored successfully
                $response["error"] = FALSE;
                $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
                $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
                $response["user"]["surname"] = $user["surname"];
                $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
                $response["user"]["age"] = $user["age"];
                $response["user"]["sex"] = $user["sex"];
                $response["user"]["status"] = $user["status"];
                $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
                $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
                echo json_encode($response);
            } else {
                // user failed to store
                $response["error"] = TRUE;
                $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters is missing!";
        $response["name"] = $_Post["name"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}catch (Exception $e) {
    System.out.println("Exception : " + $e.getMessage());
}
?>
```

and after all this is the error i am recieving :

> Array ( [first_name] => neshat [last_name] => korivand [email] => neshatkorivand@yahoo.com [Age] => 25 [gender] => 1 [status] => 1 [password] => 123456 [password_confirmation] => 123456 [t_and_c] => 1 ) {"error":true,"error_msg":"Required parameters is missing!","name":null}

Comment: `$_Post` is not the same as `$_POST`...

Comment: Also you confuse the terms name, surname, first_name and last_name...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your input response:

```
Array ( [first_name] => neshat [last_name] => korivand [email] => neshatkorivand@yahoo.com [Age] => 25 [gender] => 1 [status] => 1 [password] => 123456 [password_confirmation] => 123456 [t_and_c] => 1 ) {"error":true,"error_msg":"Required parameters is missing!","name":null}
```

These indexes:

```
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$age = $_POST['age']; 
$sex = $_POST['sex'];
```

Should be:

```
$name = $_POST['first_name']; 
$surname = $_POST['last_name'];
$age = $_POST['Age']; 
$sex = $_POST['gender'];
```

Also follow the same index names in **IF CONDITION**.

As @arkascha mentioned in his comments this:

```
$response["name"] = $_Post["name"];
```

Should be:

```
$response["name"] = $_POST["first_name"];
```

Comment: @neshat I suggest u to always use Php error_reporting in yur local environment not in production. :)